# How to make a step line with charts.JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I try to make the graph look in StepLine, but it doesn't work.
I have searched and I do not know if it is possible to do it in Charts.Js, which is where I have been doing it, any idea what I can do? This is the code

Js This is where the graph is created and I put "line" in the type, but when I put "Stepline" the graph just disappears:

```
// Load charts:
$(document).ready(function () {
  load_line_chart();
});
function load_line_chart() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("turn_over_line");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [31],
          label: "0",
          borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [31],
          label: "1",
          borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [20],
          label: "2",
          borderColor: "#3cba9f",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [10],
          label: "3",
          borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [0],
          label: "4",
          borderColor: "#c45850",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [31],
          label: "5",
          borderColor: "#c45850",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [20],
          label: "6",
          borderColor: "#c45850",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [10],
          label: "7",
          borderColor: "#c45850",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          data: [0],
          label: "8",
          borderColor: "#c45850",
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 700,
        easing: "easeInOutSine"
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Turn over per site"
      },
      responsive: false
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- semantic UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
<!--Chart js-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <br><br>
  <canvas id="turn_over_line" class="cann"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cann {
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  width: 650px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link [Stepped Line Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/stepped.html)

Its on there website. They show how to do it, and you can mess around with it.